# Shall we burninate the preposterous punless [pp] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I've recently found [pp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pp). It has no tag wiki, and  the questions tagged [pp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pp) all use it differently. Additionally, it only has 35 questions, [the earliest of which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837387/prism-silverlight) was asked almost 10 years ago, meaning that, on average, there are only about 4 questions a year asked in this tag. It does not help clarify any of the questions with this tag. It is not worth keeping it around, so I think it should be burninated.

Comment: FWIW, Q's per year is not a meaningful statistic.  It's okay for a tag to have low traffic.

Comment: It is the [perl packager](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/AUTRIJUS/PAR-0.85_01/script/pp).  Perl has not done well.

Comment: @HansPassant see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225352/why-does-ruby-evaluate-these-two-expressions-differently-the-only-difference-is, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409520/python-pp-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182677/eloqua-forms-progresive-profie-profiling. These are a few examples of questions that use the tag differently.

Comment: Well, sure, there are other users that don't really know what it means.  Such is the hazard of very short tags without a wiki.

Comment: @HansPassant because there's no tag wiki, it's not necessarily just for the perl package manager.

Comment: Changing the name to `perl-pp` may work?

Comment: @user202729 But `perl` is already in the name - [tag:perl-packager] would be better, and [tag:pretty-printer] or [tag:ruby-pp] for the Ruby pp.

Comment: Adding an except is a good start and the minimal thing we should do. Since it doesn't generate a lot of traffic, other actions might not be needed

Comment: "[Who down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idx3GSL2KWs) with, oh, [pp]?"

Comment: @HansPassant to some extent [tag:par] is used for the perl packager as well. Also a tag without excerpt and used for a variety of topics.

Comment: @Pureferret Was about to say "Is this tag out of [pp]?"

Comment: @KenY-N For python, the tagged questions relate to "Parallel Python", although python also has a native `pprint` module

Comment: [pp] needs to be quiet

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to come up with a good pun title for this tag. Damn you `pp`. Damn you

Comment: @pushkin I spent a long, long time thinking about it. Sadly, there is just not a good `pp` pun (definitely a reason to delete it :P).

Comment: Am I really the only one who thought: "Flush [pp] down the drain"?

Comment: Hey, here we go: "Be vewy vewy quiet, I'm hunting [pp]"

Comment: [Mandatory checklist for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

Comment: Is this about the [pp] tape? We shouldn't let daily politics or twitter creep in here m-)

Comment: “When I use a tag,” Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, “it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less." “The question is,” said Alice, “whether you can make tags mean so many different things.” “The question is,” said Humpty Dumpty, “which is to be master—that's all.”

Comment: There's also pp aka performance points in the game `osu!`

Comment: Yay, Robert made a synonym, so now ruby people can also tag their questions with perl-packager.

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow could introduce a tag channel system (each tag being in the namespace of its author), and have communities to opt-in for tag alignment. This would prevent tag collision like this case.

Comment: Please Put this Pointless tag in its Proper Place.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is the breakdown on how pp tag is used in the questions,

- 15 - Perl
- 7 - Ruby
- 5 - Python
- 1 (each) - Silver light, Progressive Profiling Forms and JavaScript
- 2 - PHP

I feel that the [pp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pp) tag in the [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13493601/5407188) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26323306/5407188) on PHP was mistyped instead of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

Given that most of these questions are around Perl we could rename the [pp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pp) into [perl-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-packager) as suggested in the comments and create new tags for other questions and re-tag them.

Comment: Aah! We need a trigger warning for Silverlight... ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey: And I just voted to close the Sliverlight question because it's off topic.